# Best approach to displaying Error Information to user iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

This might be an obvious question to senior and experienced developers, so I am really afraid to ask it.

Let suppose that I have a mobile app that calls too many RESTful APIs for different data models. Suppose to have ViewController A,B,C that can CRUD on these models. Now there are several things that might might go wrong. Each call has a failure block. I am using Strongloop/Loopback ios sdk.

The strategy to silently ignore the errors like this:

```
[repo logoutWithSuccess:^(){
    // ... success code
} failure:CALLBACK_FAILURE_BLOCK];
```

having defined `CALLBACK_FAILURE_BLOCK` as

```
#define ALog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define CALLBACK_FAILURE_BLOCK \
    ^(NSError *error) { \
    ALog("Callback failed: %@", error.description); \
    }
```

would be great in an ideal world where each client side validation works perfectly, and one could put his head in the sand.

Currently I have defined a helper function in each ViewController that displays an alert to the user when these calls fail.

```
[self.trip saveWithSuccess:^(){
    //... success code
} failure:^(NSError *error){
    [self displayErrorWithMessage:[error localizedDescription]
                         andTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Service Error", @"Server Error")];
}];
```

and

```
- (void)displayErrorWithMessage:(NSString*)msg andTitle:(NSString*)title{
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                                   message:msg
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                          }];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I am thinking to refactor this helper function to be in a common place, like for example AppDelegate (maybe in a protocol).

Is this a correct strategy, do you have any other best practice of how to design it better?

Comment: I think you are doing ok. But if you copy same function to whole view controllers, it means you have code duplication. Easiest way to handle it you can have base view controller for all view controller and implement this function only once. After that you can easily make manipulation on them like adding custom error view, you can give animation etc.

Comment: @Sanandrea if some one answer your question, it your job to give ur valuable feedback on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently i used this approach for one of my app and i hope it works good and easy to handle errors.

For this, i created ErrorViewController subclass of UIViewController(in My Case it is VCBaseViewController,it is the parent class for all other view controller, which s subclass of UIViewController) . you can use storyboard or xib, its up to u. i used storyboard through out my app.

My ErrorViewController.h

```
@interface ErrorViewController : VCBaseViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *errorTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *errorDescription;

@property(nonatomic,assign) ErrorPageType errorPage;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblErrorText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textViewErrorString;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnAction;

@end
```

ErrorViewController.m

```
@interface ErrorViewController ()

@end
```

@implementation ErrorViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self configureNavigationBarWithStyle:NavigationStyleBackButton];
[self setViewControllerTitle:@"Error View"];
}

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [super viewWillAppear:YES];

 switch (self.errorPage)
 {
    case ErrorTypeNetworkError:
    {

    }
        break;

    case ErrorTypeTechnicalError:
    {
        self.lblErrorText.text = @"Technical Error";
        self.textViewErrorString.text = @"Due to some technical error\n page not exist";
    }
        break;

    default:
    {
        self.lblErrorText.text = self.errorTitle;
        self.textViewErrorString.text = self.errorDescription;
    }
        break;
    }
   }

 - (IBAction)btnErrorAction:(id)sender{
 [self errorPageAction];
 }

 - (void)backButtonPressed{
 [self errorPageAction];
 }

 - (void)errorPageAction
 {
 switch (self.errorPage) 
  {
    case ErrorTypeNetworkError:
    {

    }
     break;
    case ErrorTypeProductNotAvailable:
    {
        [self popToPreviousController];
    }break;
    default:
    {
        [self popToPreviousController];
    }break;
  }
 }

 - (void)popToPreviousController
 {
  NSArray* viewcontrollers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
 if(viewcontrollers.count>2)
 {
    int index = (int)viewcontrollers.count - 3;
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewcontrollers objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];
 }else{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
 }
```

My Storyboard Design look like this, which contain error Image error labels and textView and Back Button, because i m using navigation controller.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

my BaseViewController.h

```
typedef enum {
 ErrorTypeNetworkError = 0,
 ErrorTypeTechnicalError,
 ErrorTypeNone
} ErrorPageType;

- (void)pushErrorViewcontroller:(NSError*)error;
- (void)pushErrorViewcontroller:(NSString*)errorTitle andErrorPage:(ErrorPageType)errorType;
- (void)pushErrorViewcontroller:(NSString *)errorTitle errorDescription:(NSString *)errorDescription errorType:(ErrorPageType)errorType;
```

BaseViewController.m

```
- (void)pushErrorViewcontroller:(NSString*)errorTitle andErrorPage:(ErrorPageType)errorType{
[self pushErrorViewcontroller:nil errorDescription:nil errorType:errorType];
}

- (void)pushErrorViewcontroller:(NSError*)error{
[self pushErrorViewcontroller:nil errorDescription:[error localizedDescription] errorType:ErrorTypeNone];
}

- (void)pushErrorViewcontroller:(NSString *)errorTitle errorDescription:(NSString *)errorDescription errorType:(ErrorPageType)errorType{
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ErrorViewController *errorViewController  = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ErrorViewController class])];
errorViewController.errorPage = errorType;
errorViewController.errorDescription = errorDescription;
errorViewController.errorTitle = errorTitle;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:errorViewController animated:YES];
}
```

And I m calling errorView Controller Methods in other view Controller like this.

```
- (void) ServiceCallForOrderHistoryWithCurrentPageMark: (NSString *)page
{
__block __weak VCMyOrderViewController* blockMyOrderListView = self;

[[ModelManager sharedInstance] getMyOrderDetail:[[Configuration sharedConfig] getLoggedInUserId] andPageNumber:page completionBlock:^(id result, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {        

         blockMyOrderListView.objOrderHistoryBaseClass = (OrderHistoryBaseClass *)result;

         if (blockMyOrderListView.objOrderHistoryBaseClass.rESPONSE.totalOrderCount.intValue == 0)
         {
             [blockMyOrderListView.tblMyOrder setHidden:YES];
             [blockMyOrderListView.viewNoOrders setHidden:NO];
         }
         else
         {
             [blockMyOrderListView setDataSourceMyOrders:blockMyOrderListView.objOrderHistoryBaseClass.rESPONSE];
             [blockMyOrderListView.tblMyOrder reloadData];
         }
     }
     else
     {
         [blockMyOrderListView pushErrorViewcontroller:error];
     }
 }];
}
```

Comment: Is this in line with apple's UI Design Guidelines?

Comment: @Sanandrea i guess it is based on design pattern. you can write specific mail to apple and get feedback on it. you asked it on stack so i answered here. it works for him

Comment: @Sanandrea if u r ok with my answer. plz accept it so other could get benefitted..